# Check Input Character - Pascal

Tags: function, validation, character, pascal

I'm trying to write a block of code that's going to allow me to validate an alphanumeric ID number containing upper and lower case letters along with digits.

Since its of fixed size, I have no issues isolating each part (i.e the Uppercase part, lowercase part and numeric part to be checked separately) but I'm having issues with checking for upper and lower case letters.

I've read up on the `IsUpper` and `IsLower` functions but I'm having difficulty in implementing it in my program. Is this the most efficient way to go or is there an easier route?

I'm using Pascal (Free Pascal IDE) and a sample input to be validated would be `Abc123`.

Thanks!

EDIT :

```
Program CheckChar;

VAR
UserID, LCase, UCase, Num : String;
readkey : char;
L  : Integer;


CONST
Upper = ['A'..'Z'];
Lower = ['a'..'z'];
 Int   = ['0'..'9'];

Begin
Write('Enter UserID ');Readln(UserID);
Ucase := Copy(UserID,1,1);
LCase := Copy(UserID,2,1);
Num   := Copy(UserID,3,2);
L     := Length(UserID);

  While L = 6 Do
  Begin
    IF not (Ucase in Upper) or (Lcase in Lower) or (Num in Int) then
    Begin
 Writeln('Invalid Input');
 End;
Else
 Writeln('Valid Input');
 Else
  Writeln('Invalid Length);

  End;

 readln(readkey);
  End.
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do this easily by just checking what set of characters each letter is in (borrowing from Martin Prikryl's basic function structure, but using Free Pascal's "exit" syntax):

```
function IsAlphaNumericString(s: string): boolean;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i:= 1 to length(s) do
    if not (s[i] in ['a'..'z','A'..'Z','0'..'9']) then
      exit(false);

  exit(true);
end;
```

You could also define constants for the various ranges if you wish:

```
function IsAlphaNumericString(s: string): boolean;
const
  LC_LETTERS = ['a'..'z'];
  UC_LETTERS = ['A'..'Z'];
  NUMERALS = ['0'..'9'];
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i:= 1 to length(s) do
    if not ((s[i] in LC_LETTERS) or (s[i] in UC_LETTERS) or (s[i] in NUMERALS)) then
      exit(false);
{ Or equivalently:
    if not (s[i] in LC_LETTERS)) and
       not (si[i] in UC_LETTERS) and
       not (s[i] in NUMERALS) then
      exit(false);
}
  exit(true);
end;
```

You could also have just one range of letters, such as `LETTERS = ['a'..'z']` and check `ToLower(s[i]) in LETTERS` in place of checking for `s[i]` in `LC_LETTERS` and `UC_LETTERS`.

Comment: Okay...I tried something like this but I created a Type definition for each set of characters to be checked. It didnt work. I will try my luck with this route and see if it works. Thanks!

Comment: @AbdullahZameek your question didn't show what you tried and didn't ask why that particular approach failed. In this case, you don't want to attempt to define different data types for the ranges and then see if the input somehow aligns with a data type. You don't know what range the input character will be, so you need to check it against known constant ranges. I updated my answer with that kind of example. If you find my answer acceptable, please click the "accept" check mark to indicate so.

Comment: It was my mistake, my program was almost identical to your solution except that I had assigned the letters and numbers to be type defintions intead of Const definitions. Sorry, I am quite new to the StackExchange system, still trying to get used to it :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've edited my question with the amended code (the amendment  being, changing TYPE to CONST)

Comment: @AbdullahZameek do you have a new question now? If so, then you should open a new one.

Answer (score 0):

There's [TCharacter.IsLetterOrDigit](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/character/tcharacter.isletterordigit.html):

```pascal
function IsIsLetterOrDigitString(S: string): Boolean;
begin
  for Index := 1 to Length(S) do
  begin
    if not TCharacter.IsLetterOrDigit(S[Index]) then
    begin
      Result := False;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;

  Result := True;
end;
```